# Defining a label inside Controls.Add in C#

Tags: c#, label, controls, definition

I wish to define a one time label while adding it to controls, whats the correct syntax of doing so?

for example something like this:

```
this.Controls.Add(new Label
{ 
    .BorderStyle = label1.BorderStyle,
    .BackColor = label1.BackColor,
    .Text = "Breaks",
    .Font = label1.Font,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `.` before the properties

```
this.Controls.Add(new Label
{ 
    BorderStyle = label1.BorderStyle,
    BackColor = label1.BackColor,
    Text = "Breaks",
    Font = label1.Font,
});
```

[Object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) in msdn.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

[Object and Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

```
this.Controls.Add(new Label
{ 
    BorderStyle = label1.BorderStyle,
    BackColor = label1.BackColor,
    Text = "Breaks",
    Font = label1.Font,
});
```

Make sure `label1` is exists, so, don't call it before `InitializeComponent()`

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Object Initializer for the label control, you don't require the **"."** to set the values of the properties.

Example : `Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };` from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)